# Securing files on IIS 7 and Windows Server 2008 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, iis, iis-7, authentication

What's the best practice for securing a file on an IIS 7 web application running on Windows 2008 server?

I have the following requirements and ideas:

Requirements: A authenticated user to my web app will click on a button that will create a file with data from my database. This file is sensitive and can't be downloaded. Someone with server access will be able to go and view it if necessary on the server folder.

Ideas: I create a folder on the server say C:\MyRecords. Inside that folder I used only allow what type of access? Just write and read? I should then use windows to authenticate the directory correct?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "server access?" Is this going to be exposed to the Internet?

Comment: no, someone who will remote onto the server with special permissions on the network will be able to pick it up and view it